# How to add svg to pug via mixin?

Tags: html, pug, mixins

I have a mixin

```
mixin icon(url)
  svg()
    use(xlink:href=url)
```

And the code to output

```
 -
   var features = [
      {
        icon: +icon(img/time.svg)
      }
   ]
  each item in features
    +feature(item.icon)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting something like this? I've fixed the indentation, mixin references, and stored the path to the icon as a string.

```
mixin icon(url)
  svg
    use(xlink:href=url)

-
  var features = [
    {
      icon: 'img/time.svg'
    }
  ]

each item in features
  +icon(item.icon)
```